# C# JavaScriptSerializer json array deserialization

Tags: c#, json, arraylist, arrays, javascriptserializer

**Code:**

```
string json = "[{\"Name\" : \"dan\", \"Age\" : 25, \"City\" : \"lllal\", \"About\" : \"im dan\", \"Bdate\" : \"26/06/1997\"}]";

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Person> ncontacts = ser.Deserialize<List<Person>>(json);

foreach (Person person in ncontacts)
    listView1.Items.Add(person.Name);
```

**Person Class:**

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public DateTime Bdate { get; set; }
}
```

---

The problam is that the listview stays with 0 items, even that it's supposed to have `dan`.

I've tryed to debug and i put a breakpoint on the `foreach` line, what's wierd is that it never gets to that line.. if i put a breakpoint one line before it breaks..

Any help would be welcome,
Dan

Comment: What is the contents of `ncontacts` after the Deserialize call?

Comment: when i put a breakpoint on that line it shows that it's `null`

Comment: if it's null, then Deserialize didn't work. Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date string `26/06/1997` is not in a valid format for deserialization and your code gets exception. If you replace `public DateTime Bdate { get; set; }` with `public string Bdate { get; set; }` you can see that it is working.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on his locale?

Comment: how can i change the date string to fit the valid format for deserialization instead of changing the property?

Comment: @justnS No, then serialization would have to be made depending on the receivers locale.

Comment: It's now `\"Bdate\" : \"Date(1348865672139)\"` but still not working :/

Comment: @DanBarzilay Your string does not include `/`s. (you have problem while escaping the special chars.) Try exactly this **`string json = @"{""Name"":""dan"",""Age"":25,""City"":""lllal"",""About"":""im dan"",""Bdate"":""\/Date(1348866103586)\/""}";`**